# Proof of all finite subsets on $\mathbb{R}$ together with complements is not a $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Reference- "Knowing the Odds: An introduction to probability" by John B. Walsh 2011 edition.
Ex-1.1

Show that the following class is a field, but not $\sigma$-field-

All finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ together with their complements

---

My arguments- Let class be $\mathcal{C}$. Since the there are finite subsets in $\mathcal{C}$, let $(-\infty, 1] \in \mathcal{C}$. Therefore, $(1, -\infty) \in \mathcal{C}$ because complements also exist.

Since it's not given as a condition, I think I have the right not to include $\Phi$ and $(-\infty, \infty)$. So, I can't even see $ \mathcal{C}$ as a field too, as union will produce $(-\infty, \infty) \notin \mathcal{C}$. [I must have been wrong here with something very elementary]

Even if I consider $\Phi, (-\infty, \infty) \in \mathcal{C}$, Taking the countable unions of all elements in $\mathcal{C}$ (union of all 4 elements), I will again get $\mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{C}$ which shows that countable union is in $\mathcal{C}$.

More generally, for any interval $I \in \mathcal{C}, I^C \in \mathcal{C}$. Considering $\mathbb{R}, \Phi \in \mathcal{C}$, $I\cup I^C = \mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{C}$. Now no matter hom many finite intervals are there in $\mathcal{C}$, their union will be $\mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{C}$ and hence contians all countable unions. Hence, it should be a $\sigma$-field.

---

I might have some impreciseness about the concepts and arguments. Kindly help me in correcting those.

Comment: "Since it's not given as a condition, I think I have the right not to include $\emptyset$ and $(-\infty,\infty)$." No, you don't: $\emptyset$ is a finite set and $(-\infty, \infty)$ is the complement of a finite set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\sigma$-algebra should be closed under countable unions. Does
$$
\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\{n\}
$$
belong to the class?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Logic being, if we can consider intervals in class (which have uncountably infinite elements I think), set of union should also be in class (as it contains countably infinite elements).

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Why should you consider intervals to begin with? No (proper) interval belongs to the class.

Comment: If we begin with natural numbers to be in class, when we take the complement, there are going to be intervals. Right?

Comment: And those have to be in the class [by definition].

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal The complement of $\{0\}$ is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$, which is not an interval.

Comment: okay, not interval, but union will form $\mathbb{R}$, Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72506/discussion-between-harshit-agrawal-and-egreg).